# Update all Tier prices for a product

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Without directly querying the Magento database. How can i remove all the tier prices for a certain product based on quantity and customer group?

Then add new tier prices for this product.

Example:
Remove all tier prices for a product with the SKU: FD001
where the customer group id is: 4

PHP 5.3
Magento 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using direct database queries.

As always I'm looking for a better answer.

My Hacky solution:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(9999);
$dbc = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$dbc->query('DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` WHERE `entity_id` = ' . intval($product->getId()) . ' AND `customer_group_id` IN(3,4,6,7) AND qty = 1');
$dbc->query(
    'INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`,`all_groups`,`customer_group_id`,`qty`,`value`,`website_id`)
    VALUES ('. intval($product->getId()) . ',0,' . intval($id) . ',1,' . floatval($price) . ',0)'
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

You first have to unset the tier prices and save the product, then add the tier price(s) and save again.

```
Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(123)
    ->unsTierPrice()
    ->save()
    ->setTierPrice(array(
        array(
            'website_id'    => 0,
            'all_groups'    => 0,
            'cust_group'    => 4,
            'price'         => 99.99,
            'price_qty'     => 1
        ),
        array() // another tier, etc
    ))
    ->save();
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. However between your first save and and setting the new tier price you need another load. At least for 1.9.1. `Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(123)
    ->unsTierPrice()
    ->save()
    ->load()
    ->setTierPrice(array(
        array(
            'website_id'    => 0,
            'all_groups'    => 0,
            'cust_group'    => 4,
            'price'         => 99.99,
            'price_qty'     => 1
        ),
        array() // another tier, etc
    ))
    ->save();`

Answer (score 2):

[There's an API available for the product tier price](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute_tier_price).

Alternatively, you can use some PHP code that uses the Magento code to query for a list of products that match those criteria and then adjust each one. [Alan Storm has an article about how Model Collections work (they're the type of object that you would use for this).](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections)

Basically it would be something like this to delete the products, I'm not sure how you would set the tier prices, but you can a look at [the generated phpdoc documentation](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/). I'm selecting every product that matches customer_group 4 and then deletes each product. You'll have to figure out how to filter things out based on the tier price...

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('default'); // Mage_Core_Model_App
$store = $app->getStore(); // Mage_Core_Model_Store

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
// filter out anything that doesnt match the customer group 4
$products->addFieldToFilter('customer_group', '4');

// loop through each product and delete it
for ($products->load() as $product) {
  $product->delete();
}
```

Comment: I don't need a list of tiered prices. I want to delete them based on criteria.

I was looking for something like a model that i can run delete on to remove them.

Comment: This script deletes products, which is not what the OP wanted to do at all.

Answer (score 1):

@omouse's answer pointed us to Magento's API for tier prices. [[Updated Link for Magento 1.X's Tier Price API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalogProductTierPrice.html)] Note: I'm working with Magento 1.9.2.2.

After looking around for the most efficient way to update a product's tier prices (without using direct SQL), I found the API is the fastest way. It's still slow, but it's better than the other methods I found which recommended doing something like:

```
// Works, but is slow
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->unsTierPrice();
$product->save();
$product->load();
$product->setTierPrice($tiers);
$product->save();
```

Better, I made my array of tier arrays into an array of tier objects, and used the API functions to update the product:

```
// Build the array of tier level objects
foreach ($tierLevels as $tierLevel) {
    $tiers[] = (object) array(
        'website' => 'all',
        'customer_group_id' => 'all',
        'qty' => $tierLevel['min_qty'],
        'price' => $tierLevel['unit_price']
    );
}

// Use the API to do the update
try {
    $tierPriceApi = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_tierprice_api_v2');
    $tierPriceApi->update($productId, $tiers);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched a while to find a solution, which is not pure SQL and does not need a product save, because we want to update tier prices for a catalog of 50k products, so saving all of them is surely not a solution.
I think I finally found a good way.

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_backend_tierprice')
->deletePriceData($product->getId()); 
$newTierPrice['entity_id']         = $product->getId()
$newTierPrice['all_groups']        = 1;
$newTierPrice['customer_group_id'] = 0;
$newTierPrice['qty']               = 42;
$newTierPrice['value']             = 100;
$newTierPrice['website_id']        = 0;
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_backend_tierprice')
            ->savePriceData(new Varien_Object($newTierPrice));
```